# Ignore incoming messages from user in python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm here to ask you a way to ignore incoming messages from a user in python-telegram-bot.
I'm just specifying my situation to let you aware about what the purpose of the code i'm looking for.

So this is a code for a robot, the user sends the command ***/order*** and the bot asks which drink the user wants to order.
At this point, in order ***to avoid useless overlflow***, i want to block the specific user (about 5 minutes) whom have just ordered for the sake of leaving the bot "free" for the others users.

Years ago, i looked at the specific option telegram had for groups, such as a timer chat, isn't it?
But i think is no possible at all in the private chat with the bot.

This is a simplified version of the code i'm working on.

```
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove, Update
from telegram.ext import (
    Updater,
    CommandHandler,
    MessageHandler,
    Filters,
    ConversationHandler,
    CallbackContext,
)


WORK = range(1)
def cancel(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    """Cancels and ends the conversation."""
    user = update.message.from_user
    update.message.reply_text(
        'Bye! I hope we can talk again some day.', reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    )

    return ConversationHandler.END

def order(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    update.message.reply_text("please choose a drink")
    update.message.reply_text("Sangria | Martini | Analcolico")
    return WORK

def work(update: Update, context: CallbackContext)-> int:
    ord_drink= update.message.text
    
    
    update.message.reply_text("Okay i've just received your drink, you can order your drink in 5 MINUTES")

    return ConversationHandler.END






def main() -> None:
    """Run the bot."""
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater("TOKEN")

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher


    #blocks the user after the first order for n minutes
    conv_handler2 = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('order', order)],
        states={
            WORK : [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, work)],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)],
    )

    dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler2)

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    #updater.stop()
    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**LOOK AT IT:
The blocking function for the user must be called after his order, obviously, but the bot should be free for other users**

Answer (score 0):

If this bot is running locally you can create a temporary array in which you store the id of the user that just ordered.
At the same time, you start a Job that will execute 5 minutes later and in this Job you pop the id from the array.

```py
# on top of the file
silented_user = []

# in the main function
j = updater.job_queue 


# before the order is sent
if update.effective_user.id not in silented_user:
    ...


# after the order is sent
silented_user.append(update.effective_user.id)
j.run_one(pop_user, 5*60, context={'cid_to_pop':update.effective_user.id})

def pop_user(context):
    silented_user.pop(context.job.context['cid_to_pop'])
```